# Realm Swfit Async Write Method

Tags: realm, realm-mobile-platform

I am new with swift concurrency especially Realm Swift. I have 2 sample codes where i think are the same, but it won't work

Below is the example of not working code

```
var localRealm: Realm {
    get {
        return try! Realm()
    }
}
fileprivate func testAsyncRealm() {
    self.localRealm.beginAsyncWrite {
        self.localRealm.create(SwiftStringObject.self, value: ["string2"])
        self.localRealm.commitAsyncWrite(allowGrouping: true) { error in
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

This code will throw exception
`Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason: Can only add, remove, or create objects in a Realm in a write transaction - call beginWriteTransaction on an RLMRealm instance first.`

However, below code will work without any problem

```
fileprivate func testAsyncRealm() {
    let realm = try! Realm()
    realm.beginAsyncWrite {
        realm.create(SwiftStringObject.self, value: ["string2"])
        realm.commitAsyncWrite(allowGrouping: true) { error in
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

What am I missing here? Thanks...

Realm Version: 10.40.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a theory but fits the issue

When a realm object begins an async write transaction, it appears a flag is set on that realm `isPerformingAsynchronousWriteOperations` to indicate it's in an async write. For example

```
var realm = try! Realm()
        
realm.beginAsyncWrite {
   let isWrite = realm.isPerformingAsynchronousWriteOperations
   print("is write? \(isWrite)") //outputs true
}
```

However, in your code (abbreviated)

```
var localRealm: Realm {
    get {
        return try! Realm()
    }
}
fileprivate func testAsyncRealm() {
    self.localRealm.beginAsyncWrite {
       let isWrite = self.localRealm.isPerformingAsynchronousWriteOperations
       print("is write? \(isWrite)") //outputs false
    }
}
```

the output is false - indicating that the flag was not set so Realm doesn't think its in an asynch write.

I'll propose the behavior is because each time the var is accessed via `self.localRealm`, it re-initializes Realm, with that flag being false.

The simple solution is to work with the same instance of Realm without re-initializing it

```
fileprivate func doAsyncWrite() {
   var realm = self.localRealm  //gets a realm instance
        
   realm.beginAsyncWrite { //use that same realm to write, which sets the flag
      let isWrite = realm.isPerformingAsynchronousWriteOperations
      print("is write? \(isWrite)") //returns true
   }
}
```

With that change, the code in the question works correctly.

Comment: Very good explanation. it makes sense now! Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You catch bad exception because you try to perform two write-transactions asynchronously at once. Their documentation says you need to perform only one transaction at one time. You can fix it by a few options:

1. Calling `@escaping` callback after each transaction.
2. Write `@propertyWrapper` for your realm object and inject semaphore and implement its logic to avoid multiple working transactions at once.
3. If you don't want to work on serial queue due to UI glitches, it makes sense to implement its own concurrent queue right inside `@propertyWrapper` and implement all the logic inside wrapper on that queue.

The reason why these operations in Realm **are not** thread-safe is their idea to avoid ["race conditions"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) basically. How can we handle it — it is up to us.

---

Just a quote from their doc about `asynWrite<Result>(:)`:

> This function differs from synchronous `write` in that it suspends the
> calling task while waiting for its turn to write rather than blocking the
> thread. In addition, the actual i/o to write data to disk is done by a
> background worker thread. For small writes, using this function on the
> main thread may block the main thread for less time than manually
> dispatching the write to a background thread.

> If the block throws an error, the transaction will be canceled and any
> changes made before the error will be rolled back.

> Only one write transaction can be open at a time for each Realm file. Write
> transactions cannot be nested, and trying to begin a write transaction on a
> Realm which is already in a write transaction will throw an exception.
> Calls to `write` from `Realm` instances for the same Realm file in other
> threads or other processes will block until the current write transaction
> completes or is cancelled.

---

Cheers.